# How to change progress bar direction

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use progressBar but I would like to change direction of it.
by default all progressbar's filled out from left to right. but I want right to left. there are some libraries but they are free of this configure.

for example:

https://github.com/rafaelmotta/react-native-progress-bar-animated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a hack which you can try.

You can put the progress bar inside a "View" Component and rotate the "View" to a 180degree.

```
progressBarContainer: {
   transform: [{ rotate: '180deg'}]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with React Native itself, but you might want to try using a library like [this](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#loading-section/progress) and then making the progress bar go backwards.

For example (pseudocode):

```
<div id="p1" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress"></div>
<script>
  let someNumber = 100
  document.querySelector('#p1').addEventListener('mdl-componentupgraded', function() {
    someNumber -= 1
    this.MaterialProgress.setProgress(someNumber);
  });
</script>
```

You can style the progress bar to switch the colors.